# Idle Timeout of Authentication Tokens

Tags: python, flask, access-token

I have an app using Flask and SQLAlchemy that allows users to make calls to a RESTful API using authentication tokens which I provide to them when they log into the application. One of the requirements of the application is that if a user is **idle** for 15 minutes, their token should expire and they will be required to log into the application again to get a new one.

Currently I am doing this by storing a user's session in a table

```
class Session(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship('User')
    creation_time = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    last_active = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now)

    _serializer = Serializer('foobar')

    def is_active(self):
        return (datetime.now() - self.last_active) < timedelta(15*60)

    def create_token(self, token):
        return self._serializer.dumps({
            'session_id': self.id, 
            'user_id': self.user_id,
        })

    @staticmethod
    def from_token(self, token):
        try:
            data = self._serializer.loads(token)
        except BadSignature:
            return None

        session = Session.query.get(data.get('session_id'))
        if session and session.is_active() and session.user_id == data.get('user_id'):
            # Refresh the session
            session.last_active = datetime.now()
            return session

class User(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String)

    def generate_token(self):
        return Session(self.id).create_token()

    def verify_auth_token(token):
        session = Session.from_token(token)
        if session:
            return session.user
```

Is there a more elegant and efficient way of doing this? I have seen many examples where the token stores the creation time and the tokens are only valid for a  specific amount of time (which allows for an easy test without having to know what user it is, etc.), but I haven't been able to find any information about the expiration based on a user's idle time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the potential bug because `session.last_active = …` is set without a call to `session.flush()` (where that's the SQLAlchemy Session), this is a totally reasonable way to do it.

In general, sites use a non-relational datastore (ex, Redis) for session management because it can be more performant (RDBMSs tend to be slower for writes, and especially in this case you'll be doing a lot of writes).

The logic would still be the same, though:

```
def session_from_token(token):
    key = "session:%s" %(token, )
    session_json = redis.get(key)
    if not session_json:
        return None
    session = json.loads(session_json)
    if not session.get("is_valid"):
        return None
    redis.expire(key, 15 * 60)
    return session
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on this. So if I'm understanding this correctly, calling redis.expire() on an existing key essentially "refreshes" that token so it's good for another 15 minutes?

Comment: Yep, exactly. Now, there is also a race condition in this code (if the key expires between being read and having the expiry updated), so you might want to go with something a tad more complex… but it's the right general idea.